# Comparing two strings with special characters via charCodeAt

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

My goal is to create a method which takes two strings with special characters and properly compares them. I'm struggling with understanding the logistics of character encoding.

So, my string looks like:

> Häzel - This Girl Is Watching Me

I have two copies of this string. One was provided to me via a third-party API via $.ajax() and the other is a de-serialization from my server, also using $.ajax().

My original string, when represented as char codes, looks like:

```
Array[33]
0: 72
1: 97
2: 776
3: 122
4: 101
5: 108
6: 32
7: 45
8: 32
9: 84
10: 104
11: 105
12: 115
13: 32
14: 71
15: 105
16: 114
17: 108
18: 32
19: 73
20: 115
21: 32
22: 87
23: 97
24: 116
25: 99
26: 104
27: 105
28: 110
29: 103
30: 32
31: 77
32: 101
```

and afterwards:

```
Array[32]
0: 72
1: 228
2: 122
3: 101
4: 108
5: 32
6: 45
7: 32
8: 84
9: 104
10: 105
11: 115
12: 32
13: 71
14: 105
15: 114
16: 108
17: 32
18: 73
19: 115
20: 32
21: 87
22: 97
23: 116
24: 99
25: 104
26: 105
27: 110
28: 103
29: 32
30: 77
31: 101
```

with the difference being the "ä" is represented as [97, 776] before serialization and [228] after serialization.

I'm wondering a few things:

- Is it clear from this information what encoding is being used? I'm unfamiliar with the process and Googling is turning up a lot about alt + numpad key combinations, but I do not believe that's correct.
- Is it possible to 'cast' one of my strings as the other?
- Is it possible to create a generic 'comparator' function which could equate these two strings as equal?

In my mind they are exactly the same. I have no preference on encoding at this point in time -- I only wish for the two strings to be equatable.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to compare the output if the before and after values are adjacent. You could probably have used a much shorter string too. BTW, 228 is the HTML encoding (`&#228;`) for ä, the character entity is `&auml;`. The ASCII code is 132. Doesn't the documentation for the interface tell you what encoding is used? These things are difficult to guess.

Comment: The data comes from $.ajax(); requests I am making. The documentation for jQuery says that UTF-8 is forced. I guess I don't understand how I could receive an oddly-encoded string from my response?

Comment: You may be able to convert the decomposed char codes to composed (i.e. 97,776 to 228) using the javascript code at [Normalization code](http://rishida.net/blog/?p=222). There is a PHP variant too.

Comment: @RobG There is no ASCII over 127. The Unicode — and Latin-1 and ISO 859-1 and ISO 8859-15 — code point is 228. I don’t what weirdo system you’re ysing that thinks this is 132, but it sure as Sherlock isn’t ASCII or any normal standard encoding.

Comment: I don’t see any special characters in your string.  What are you talking about? Those are all non-special.

Comment: @tchrist—who mentioned ISO? ä is 132 in the weirdo extended ASCII character set introduced by IBM in 1981 (also called ["code page 437"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) and used by all IBM-compatible PCs ever since (even those using MS-DOS). But I suspect you knew that. ;-) But your inference is probably correct, it seems an ISO encoding was used.

Comment: @RobG Actually I’ve never done Microsoft, so I had no idea. And I don’t “believe” in “extended” ASCII, since ASCII is ASCII. And “code page” is a negative-flash-word for us Unix types, who use “charset”, just like your MIME specs do.

Comment: Damn, don't run into many green–screeners these days! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is a sequence of bytes. As such, it cannot be rendered as anything except as bit pattern. Next, a character set comes into play. Here, you map numbers to characters, for example 65 to `A`, 97 to `a` and 228 to `ä`. Finally, you need a character encoding, which maps the number to a bit pattern.

For number 228, the usual 8-bit encoding simply uses `0xE4` as bit pattern. UTF-8 encoding will use `0xC3 0xA4` as bit pattern and UTF-16 will use `0x00 0xE4` as bit pattern.

So in order to properly compare a string, you need to know its bit pattern (byte sequence), its encoding and its character set. If you lack any, strings cannot be properly compared.

Nowadays, Unicode is used as character set most of the time. If you only use the very basic characters, ASCII will do the job as well. ASCII is a subset of Unicode as the first 127 characters (code points) are the same. For encoding, 7-bit ASCII is the same as UTF-8.

So in short, without knowing character set and character encoding (or at least knowing that they are the same for both strings), you cannot compare strings at all.

Comment: True, but it seems that the OP is comparing [fully decomposed values with fully composed values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), and therefore may (for this specific case) be able to convert one to the other before comparison. Just guessing though.

Comment: Taken from Wikipedia: "However, they are not injective (they map different original glyphs and sequences to the same normalized sequence) and thus also not bijective (can't be restored). For example, the distinct Unicode strings "U+212B" (the angstrom sign "Å") and "U+00C5" (the Swedish letter "Å") are both expanded by NFD (or NFKD) into the sequence "U+0041 U+030A" (Latin letter "A" and combining ring above "°") which is then reduced by NFC (or NFKC) to "U+00C5" (the Swedish letter "Å")." - So even this can lead to false positives.